# Why double counting occurs in one solution?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

My question is why repetition occurs in some particular solutions of questions

For example let's suppose a question paper have 12 questions and two section 'A' and 'B' . Section 'A' have  7 questions and section 'B' have 5 questions . At least 3 questions are to be answered from both section and only 8 questions are to be answered in total.Find total number of ways it can be done.

$Method-1(wrong)$

Number of ways of Choosing three question from both section a and b simultaneously are

$^7C_3 ×\, ^5C_3\,=\,350$

Now out of 12 questions we have picked 6 questions and also fulfilled the criteria of choosing 3 questions per section

Now we have to choose two more question out of the remaining 6 questions

$^6C_2\, =\, 15$

So total number of ways of choosing 8 questions out of 12 question with given conditions are

$350×15=5250$

$M-2(correct)$

Total number of ways of choosing 8 question - [(choosing 1 question from section b and 7 from a) + (choosing 2 question from section b and 6 from a)]

I chose conditions of b only to exclude because even if we take all questions from b(i.e 5) 3 question can still be chosen from a , so condition can only be violated from above two cases

After solving answer comes out to be 420

Now there's a big difference in answer in method 1 and method 2 so the only possible reason is that there is huge number of repetition in Method 1 so why does it happen like what are some cases of repetition as it is here to visualize.

Answer (score 3):

Here's why the first method is wrong.

Say, in the first step (when you choose $3$ questions each from the two sections), one of the questions chosen is A1 - the first question in section A.

Then in the next step (choosing the last $2$ questions, unrestricted), you choose A4.

The method counts this as one possibility.

But consider this. You choose A4 in the first step and A1 in the next. This is also counted as a distinct possibility.

But they are one and the same thing (assuming everything else remains the same). In both the scenarios you have A1, A4 - along with six other questions that are also the same.

See the problem?